# Add column based on values from columns of two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames, DF1 has many columns and `tag` column which has duplicate values:

```
... tag
... cat
... dog
... cat
... pencil
... ...
```

DF2 has two columns, `tag` and `type`, `tag` values are unique, `type` are not:

```
tag    type
car    vehicle
cat    animal  
dog    animal
pencil object
...    ...
```

It's not necessarily true that each tag from DF1 is described in DF2. I'd like to add column to DF1 which would contain type for each tag, for example:

```
... tag     type
... cat     animal
... dog     animal
... cat     animal
... pencil  object
... ...
```

Type for any tags from DF1 which are not in DF2 should be NA.

I made a loop to solve this, but it's very slow for a bigger data set. I assume that something like this can be done more elegant in R?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
Total <- merge(DF1, DF2, by="type")
```

It will give you 3 columns. What you want is 1st and 3rd column. So remove the 2nd column.

Comment: this will not work - default of merge is inner join. `merge(DF1, DF2, by = "type", all.x = TRUE)` would work

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with dplyr (among other methods). Try:

```
library("dplyr")

total <- DF1 %>% left_join(DF2)
```